# Hide/Display 'Clear' Button when Filter has been used

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem in hiding a clear button until filter options have been selected.

I have 4 asp:DropDownList's and an 'Apply Filter' button.  When an option is selected the user has to click the 'Apply Filter' button.

Beside the 'Apply' button, I have the 'Clear/Reset' button which when you click it, will reset the asp:DropDownList's back to their defaults.

What I want is to only display the 'Clear/Reset' button when any of the asp:DropDownList's do not equal their default.  Please bar in mind that a user could use filter 2 & 3 and leave filter's 1 & 4 as default's so the code would have to take this in mind.

I want the best way to do this as I have been all over Google and cant find the answer I need.

**My default.aspx:**

```
 <dl class="filterlist" style="margin-top: -5px">
      <dt>
          <asp:Label ID="Environment" runat="server" Text="Environment" AssociatedControlID="EnvironmentDD" />
      </dt>
      <dd>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="EnvironmentDD" runat="server" ToolTip="Filter the table below by environment." Width="135px" />
      </dd>
      <dt>
          <asp:Label ID="Product" runat="server" Text="Product" AssociatedControlID="ProductDD" />
      </dt>
      <dd>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ProductDD" runat="server" ToolTip="Filter the table below by product." Width="135px" />
      </dd>
      <dt>
          <asp:Label ID="TestType" runat="server" Text="Test Type" AssociatedControlID="TestTypeDD" />
      </dt>
      <dd>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="TestTypeDD" runat="server" ToolTip="Filter the table below by test type." Width="135px" />
      </dd>
      <dt>
          <asp:Label ID="ProductType" runat="server" Text="Product Type" AssociatedControlID="ProductTypeDD" />
      </dt>
      <dd>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ProductTypeDD" runat="server" ToolTip="Filter the table below by product type." Width="135px" />
      </dd>
 </dl>

 <div class="button">
      <asp:Button CssClass="butstyle" ID="ApplyFilter" runat="server" onclick="ApplyFilters_Click" Text="Apply Filter(s)" />&nbsp;
      <asp:Button CssClass="butstyle" ID="ClearFilters" runat="server" onclick="ClearFilters_Click" Text="Clear Filter(s)"
                    Tooltip="Click this button to reset any filters set." />
 </div>
```

The asp:DropDownList's are populated in my code behind as they generate a asp:DataGrid table from SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add a common CSSClass to all the drop-downs and hook an event on `change` of these drop-down.

**For example, I have used `mydropdown` class and considering the default value as `1`.**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".mydropdown").on("change", function () {
        var totalDropdown = $(".mydropdown").length;
        var unchangedDropDown = $(".mydropdown").filter(function () {
            return $(this).find("option:selected").val() == 1;
        }).length;

        console.log(unchangedDropDown);
        if (totalDropdown === unchangedDropDown) {
            $(".butstyle").hide();
        } else {
            $(".butstyle").show();
        }

    });
});
```

<kbd>[Simulation](http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/d2uZx/)</kbd>

Comment: @Antony - Does this answer your query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write a complete answer, but this is what I would do:

In your ApplyFilter event handler, check to make sure that one of the drop downs has been selected. If one has, then actually apply the filter rules that you have, and set ClearFilters.Visible = true;  You can determine if the dropdown is at its initial state by checking the value of the [DropDownList.SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then in your clear filter event handler just set ClearFilters.visible = false; (along with removing whatever filters you have)